# Vector class type changes on editing JTable

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable

I have a JTable which has three columns:

String, PropertyItem (Custom class), String

PropertyItem is *displayed* as a String in the table but type is PropertyItem. Here is a sample row of table:

Value Mask | Format Constraints | Value Mask Rule Sub Type

The table's data is fetched using a Vector:

```
List<Vector> displayedData = table_propertyDetails.getDataMatrix();
```

and traversing the table data like this:

```
for(Vector row : displayedData) { ... }
```

Now, row.get(index) function is used to fetch the column data with typecasting to String for column 0 and 2. For PropertyItem column, it is done as (PropertyItem) row.get(index). So, far things are good and no problems appear in normal listing/fetching of rows.

Now, when this table's second column (PropertyItem) is edited, it turns into a String and (PropertyItem) row.get(index) returns in an error for that row:

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   com.abc.xyz.model.PropertyItem

For all other rows in which data is not edited, this casting is done without any error but with the edited row, it results in this error.

Any idea what I can do here to convert the String back to PropertyItem at this time or before this time?

Answer (score 3):

Seems, you use **DefaultTableModel**, in this case I recommend you to write your own  [TableCellEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) for editing your custom column. In your implementation you can edit your object as you wish.

Comment: Sorry for not replying or marking on your answer. My situation ended up even more difficult and was solved by changing the logic in the code. Thanks for your answer anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand the explanation and writing answer WRT my past errors.

I think you need to review the `TableModel` of your `JTable`, which DataType you are setting while creating the `JTable`.

If you are using `String` for all three columns than change it to `Object` for second column.

Because you are adding a `String` in first and third column it will work, but you are adding Object of `PropertyItem` in second column and DataType of second column may be `String` this will be converted to `String` and `get()` method will return a String from table and that Casting error will occurs.

I hope, Changing the Type of second column in `TableModel` will solve the issue.

**Example :**

```
myTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null},
        {null, null, null},
        {null, null, null},
        {null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"
    }
    ) {
    Class[] types = new Class [] {
        java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.String.class
    };

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return types [columnIndex];
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying or marking on your answer. My situation ended up even more difficult and was solved by changing the logic in the code. Thanks for your answer anyways :)

Comment: Sorry man, I didn't implement your solution so not sure if it is correct :|